# Which sentence is correct "being" or 'having been' or when he was?

Tags: grammar

1. Being a child, he could not understand how severe the situation was.
2. As a child, he lived with his parents abroad for a long time.

Questions about first sentence: should I use 'being a child' or 'having been a child' because it’s about the past? Or maybe there is any other option to say that?

Questions about second sentence: should I use 'as a child' or 'being a child' or 'when he was a child'?

Answer (score 1):

1. *Being a child, he could not understand...* If you wanted to use *having been a child*, you would have to continue *he had not understood.*
2. *As a child* implies *when he was a child*, so you can use either - but not *being a child*, which has the sense *because he was a child.*

Comment: I'm not sure how likely it is that you'd want to use ***having been a child*** to "explain" anything! Maybe it's worth saying ***having had a child*** in some contexts, because not everyone is a *parent*, so it could be relevant to mention that "special background". But since everyone ***was*** a child (apart from those who are *still **being** children*), that wouldn't normally be "useful information".

Comment: ...but [here's](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22for+as+a+dutiful+son+he%22) *Her solitude in extreme old age shocks him, for **as a dutiful son** he had cared for his mother until her death...* Where I'd be inclined to say ***being*** would be maybe *slightly* more "elegant", but both versions are fine, and they both carry the ***because*** sense, not ***when, at that time***.